# POSIX flags - how to set all of them / individual ones

Tags: c, posix

I have this peice of code that should read from a pseudo terminal and print to another pseudo terminal (stdin):

```
// Declare & define a file descriptor.
int fd;

int status;
char string[] = "XXXX";
char buffer[8];

// Establish connection between a file and the file descriptor.
fd = open("/dev/pts/4", O_RDWR);

// Check if connection was established.
if(fd == -1){
    printf("Assigning failed: %s\n", strerror(errno));
}
else{
    fputs("Assigning successful!\n", stdout);
    // Set some flags for the connection.
    fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, 0);
}
   
// Read from the connection.
status = read(fd, buffer, 8);
if (status == -1){
    printf("Read failed: %s\n", strerror(errno));
}
else{
    printf("I read this: %s\n", buffer);
}

return 0;
```

I don't know exactly what `fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, 0);` does, but untill I used it I wasn't able to read from the `/dev/pts/4`. After I used it for the first time I could read normaly, even if I commented out this line of code.

I tried to explain it to myself reading POSIX...

`F_SETFL` flag is defined in the POSIX as:

> Set the file **status** flags, defined in <fcntl.h>, for the file
> description associated with fildes from the corresponding bits in the
> third argument, arg, taken as type int. Bits corresponding to the file
> access mode and the file creation flags, as defined in <fcntl.h>, that
> are set in arg shall be ignored. If any bits in arg other than those
> mentioned here are changed by the application, the result is
> unspecified. If fildes does not support non-blocking operations, it is
> unspecified whether the O_NONBLOCK flag will be ignored.

So it sets file **status** flags asociated with the 1st argument (file descriptor) of `fnctl()` to `0`? I found an explanation about the **status** flags in the POSIX:

> The `<fcntl.h>` header shall define the following symbolic constants for
> use as file status flags for `open()`, `openat()`, and `fcntl()`. The values
> shall be suitable for use in #if preprocessing directives.
>
> `O_APPEND` Set append mode. `O_DSYNC` Write according
> to synchronized I/O data integrity completion. `O_NONBLOCK`
> Non-blocking mode. `O_RSYNC` Synchronized read I/O
> operations. `O_SYNC` Write according to synchronized I/O
> file integrity completion.

So does `fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, 0);` set all those to `0`? Are all of those flags a single bit? How do I only set one of them to `1` or `0`? And how do I know which bit is assigned to which flag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bitmask.  Each flag is a bit (or several bits) in the integer you pass to `fcntl`.  Each symbolic constant expands to a number in which only the corresponding bit(s) is set, and so you can set several flags by ORing them together.  For instance, if bit 2 is the append flag, then `O_APPEND` would be `0b100 == 4`; if bit 3 is the nonblock flag, then `O_NONBLOCK` would be `0b1000 == 8`, and so on.  But by using the symbolic constants, you don't need to know which bits they actually are, which is good since they may vary between OSes.

In `fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, 0)`, the number 0 has no bits set, so all the flags are cleared.  To set append and clear the rest, you could do `fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, O_APPEND);`.  To set both append and nonblock, OR their constants together: `fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, O_APPEND | O_NONBLOCK);`

With similar bit operations, you can operate on the flags returned by `fl = fcntl(fd, F_GETFL)`:

```
int fl = fcntl(fd, F_GETFL);
if (fl & O_APPEND) { ... } // test if in append mode
fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, fl | O_NONBLOCK); // turn on nonblock and keep everything else the same
fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, fl & ~O_DSYNC); // turn off dsync and keep everything else the same
```

There's some more examples [here](https://www.eskimo.com/%7Escs/cclass/int/sx4ab.html).

Comment: In the code that you posted... What is the role of `fl`? Do we assign it all the masks at once? So that you can later use it to remove the flags?

Comment: @71GA It's the current flags.

Comment: @Shawn How would you then set all the flags on at the same time? Probably this is not possible except by specifying all the flags... Probably this would create also some sort of the undefined behaviour?

Comment: @71GA: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking.  `fcntl(fd, F_GETFL)` returns the current flags.  So in my example, if the fd currently has the append and nonblock flags set, and no others, then `fl` would get set to `0b1100 == 12`.  I don't know what you mean by "set all the flags on at the same time".  Taken literally that would look like `fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, -1)` since `-1 = 0xffffffff` in two's complement arithmetic has all bits set, but that will probably fail as it may ask to set bits that do not correspond to any flag.  It couldn't possibly be useful in any case.

Comment: @71GA You'd or together all the flags that can be set on your OS. Refer to `man 2 fcntl` or other appropriate documentation to see what they are.

Comment: @Shawn I understand that his is not possible. I just wanted to double check. Okay I understand the POSIX flags now! Thanks!